# mysql how to find if at least one row from cross reference table is null or criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, having, cross-reference, ifnull

i have trouble with mysql, i dont find the way to do it maybe i dont know the good mysql keyword

mysql5

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| ID       | FOREIGNKEY |  TRAINER |
+----------+------------+----------+
|      ... | ...        | ...      |
|      475 | 254        |  NULL    |
|      476 | 254        |  NULL    |
|      477 | 254        |  NULL    |
|      478 | 286        |  NULL    |
|      479 | 286        |  FREE    |
|      480 | 286        |  FREE    |
|      481 | 401        |  FREE    |
|      482 | 401        |  1       |
|      483 | 401        |  FREE    |
|      484 | 405        |  NULL   |
|      485 | 405        |  1       |
|      486 | 405        |  5       |
|      487 | 405        |  FREE    |
|      488 | 406        |  1       |
|      489 | 406        |  5       |
|      490 | 406        |  5       |
|      491 | 406        |  2       |
|      ... | ...        |  ...     |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

**Expected result**

Constraint :

i would like to get all the foreignkey id that have not all trainer NULL or FREE (at least 1 but can be 2 or more) but at least one should be NULL

```
+------------+-------+
|    ID_TR   | FIELD |
+------------+-------+
|      405   |   ..  |
+------------+-------+
```

i dont know how to do it in mysql ?
Group then HAVING one trainer == FREE OR NULL ?

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classic usecase for the `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   mytable b
               WHERE  a.foreignkey = b.foreignkey 
               AND    trainer IS NOT NULL 
               AND    trainer <> 'FREE'
```

**EDIT:**
If you just just want the distinct different `foreignkey`s:

```
SELECT DISTINCT foreignkey
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   mytable b
               WHERE  a.foreignkey = b.foreignkey 
               AND    trainer IS NOT NULL 
               AND    trainer <> 'FREE'
```

Comment: exists looks good but it returns 15 rows , i think there is a problem

Comment: After re-looking at the OP, I think my edit should answer the question. If not, please elaborate why this differs from the output you need. Thanks!

Comment: sorry i got 286, 401, 405, 406 and i only need 405 because he has one row with NULL and one different FROM NULL OR FREE

Comment: should i use another exists  for at least one null row ?

Comment: i tried :

SELECT DISTINCT id_tr FROM planning_requests a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM planning_requests b WHERE a.id_tr = b.id_tr AND trainer IS NOT NULL AND trainer <> 'FREE' ) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM planning_requests b WHERE a.id_tr = b.id_tr AND trainer IS NULL )

but i got 286 and 405, it isnt good

Comment: hum finally double exists looks working i had FREE2 in one ROW ... do you think its a good solution ?

Comment: Why do you need the double `EXISTS`? If you have a `FREE2` entry you should either fix it, or add and additional clause `AND trainer <> 'FREE2'`

Comment: yes i fixed it to works but i need double exists for the other one condition that is at least one NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   t.*
FROM     my_table    t
    JOIN cross_table x ON x.FOREIGNKEY = t.ID_TR
WHERE    x.TRAINER IS NOT NULL
     AND x.TRAINER <> 'FREE'
GROUP BY t.ID_TR
```

Comment: :-( I don't like to see GROUP BY used this way, not even by gurus

Comment: @Strawberry: What about it don't you like?  The selection of non-aggregated columns in MySQL is a *deliberate* feature that gives a significant performance boost...

Comment: @juhnz: From your sample data, I'd expect to see IDs 401, 405 and 406 in the results (they all have at least one record whose `TRAINER` column is neither `NULL` nor `'FREE'`).  Is this not what you were after?

Comment: I admit that it's an aesthetic dislike - although 'significant'? Are you sure?

Comment: oh well sorry i means 1 column is neither NULL OR FREE + 1 column at least NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number that are `'FREE'` and `NULL` and then do logic:

```
select foreignkey,
       sum(trainer is null) as NumNulls,
       sum(trainer = 'Free') as NumFrees,
       count(*) as Num
from table t
group by foreignkey
```

You then want to add a having clause to get what you want.  I am not sure exactly what this means:  "i would like to get all the foreignkey id that have not all trainer NULL or FREE (at least 1 but can be 2 or more) but at least one should be NULL".

For instance, this might be what you want:

```
having NumNulls > 0 and NumFrees > 0
```

or perhaps this:

```
having NumNulls > 0 and NumFrees > 0 and cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: after modifying a bit your requests it seems working  but what is better for big table having or exists ?

select id_tr
from planning_requests t
group by id_tr
having sum(trainer is NULL) > 0 and sum(trainer <> 'FREE' AND trainer IS NOT NULL) > 0

and what do you use to format SQL code on stackoverflow ?

Comment: @juhnz . . . If you have indexes on the table, then you can probably optimize `exists` to have better performance.  Aggregation and `having` are more flexible for describing different possible conditions.

Comment: ok then i think i will use exists because having looks to slow atm. what do you use for SQL Formatting on stack overflow ? thx

Comment: @juhnz . . . I have my own style of writing SQL.  I format it myself.