# MYSQL how to speed up requests using EXISTS

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, exists

i have an SQL Requests:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_tr 
FROM planning_requests a 
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM planning_requests b 
        WHERE a.id_tr = b.id_tr 
        AND trainer IS NOT NULL 
        AND trainer != 'FREE' 
      ) 
AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM planning_requests c
        WHERE a.id_tr = c.id_tr 
        AND trainer IS NULL 
    )
```

but this requests take 168.9490 sec to execute for returning 23162 rows of 2545088 rows
should i use LEFT JOIN or NOT IN ? and how can i rewrite it thx

Comment: Why don't you give it a try for yourself? You might actually learn something.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363523/mysql-how-to-find-if-at-least-one-row-from-cross-reference-table-is-null-or-crit/21363586#21363586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed this up by adding indexes.  I would suggest:  `planning_requests(id_tr, trainer)`.

You can do this as:

```
create index planning_requests_id_trainer on planning_requests(id_tr, trainer);
```

Also, I think you are missing an `=` in the first subquery.

EDIT:

If you have a lot of duplicate values of `id_tr`, then in addition to the above indexes, it might make sense to phrase the query as:

```
select id_tr
from (select distinct id_tr
      from planning_requests
     ) a
where . . .
```

The `where` conditions are being run on every row of the original table.  The `distinct` is processed after the `where`.

Comment: good informations, i compare now with distinct then i will try to create an index. shoud i call planning_requests_id_trainer  in request or its automatic ?

Comment: without distinct on first id_tr , request is really too much long and froze mysql server xD

Comment: @juhnz . . . It froze the SQL server even with the index in the answer?

Comment: no i just try without index atm, i just have to create index ? or should i call index in request ?

Comment: Just create the index.  MySQL will know what to do with it.

Comment: creating index through phpmyadmin is very slow , is better to use mysql.exe to do it ?

Comment: I would do it through mysql.exe, but it will probably take a few minutes to create the index -- you have a lot of data.

Comment: index improved seriously performance thx (>2Million records > 1hour ;p)

Answer (score 0):

I think your query can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id_tr 
FROM planning_requests a
JOIN planning_requests b
ON b.id_tr = a.id_tr
AND b.trainer IS NULL
WHERE a.trainer < 'FREE'
```

If you index planning_requests(trainer), then MySQL can utilize an index range to get all the rows that aren't `FREE` or `NULL`. All numeric strings will meet the `< 'FREE'` criteria, and it also won't return `NULL` values.

Then, use `JOIN` to make sure each record from that much smaller result set has a matching `NULL` record.

For the `JOIN`, index planning_requests(id_tr, trainer).

It might be simpler if you don't mix types in a column like `FREE` and `1`.

Comment: and if i trainer can be FREE and FREE2,

SELECT DISTINCT a.id_tr 
FROM planning_requests a
JOIN planning_requests b
ON b.id_tr = a.id_tr
AND b.trainer IS NULL
WHERE a.trainer < 'FREE' OR a.trainer < 'FREE2' > does it work ? VALUE OR TRAINER EQUALS NULL OR VARCHAR (FREE,FREE2,1,2,3...)

Comment: with exists requests : 23162 returns and with your requests 30907 returns

Comment: What's `FREE2`? We only know what you tell us. Best way to ask how to optimize a query is to tell us what you're doing, not how you're doing it. This means, schema, sample data, and record counts.